# Dismissing android view after a timer

Tags: java, android

I currently have an app which loads a screen, OpenActivity, which, has a button saying 'start' which when pressed takes you to MenuActivity.class, actually, the button itself is just a view, and anywhere on the screen can be pressed, you will still go to the MenuActivity.

What I would like to do, is change it so, that the OpenActivity class appears as normal, however, dismisses by itself, after say, 3 seconds, to then show MenuActivity.
Although if possible, to be able to control the dismiss action, for example;

Start the App
'OpenActiviy' screen shows for 3 seconds, then dismisses to show MenuActivity, with a callback so I can do something on dismiss OpenActivity BEFORE the MenuActivity shows, I hope this makes sense!

OnCreate for OpenActivity;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.open_app);

    Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.disk);
    findViewById(R.id.viewOpenApp).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(OpenActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Handler:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //dismiss the view, start the activity or anything else you need
        }
    }, 3000); // time to wait before executing  the code inside run() in milliseconds
```